# Saving a shapefile to an output file path in my function(which the user will provide)?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, path

I have a function which takes the coordinate argument from the user and converts it to a shapefile, and finally saves that shapefile to the filepath that the user gives. This is the code...

```
epsg_code = int(input('Enter epsg code: '))
outfilepath = input('Enter filepath for where the shapefile should be stored(r"\\...\\..\\"): ')

def geodf(coords):
    from shapely.geometry import Polygon
    import geopandas as gpd
    from fiona.crs import from_epsg
    import os

    coords_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
    coords_poly = Polygon(coords)
    coords_poly

    coords_gdf.loc[0, 'geometry'] = coords_poly
    coords_gdf.crs = from_epsg(epsg_code)
    coords_gdf.crs
    return coords_gdf.plot(color = 'brown')

    #coords_gdf.to_file(os.path.join(outfilepath))#, *coords_gdf.shp ))
    coords_gdf.to_file(outfilepath + coords.shp)
    #outfilepath + "\\coords_gdf.shp")
```

a_coords =  [(659337, 737770), (659335, 737703), (659329, 737702) ,(659328, 737700), (659282, 737700), (659268, 737749), (659296, 737767)]   #example

epsg_code = 32630

geodf(a_coords)

But the shapefile doesn't get saved to the filepath I put in.

Comment: Use os.path.join to combine path and filename instead of outfilepath + coords.shp.

Comment: Thanks @BERA, I just tried ` coords_gdf.to_file(os.path.join(outfilepath, coords_gdf.shp))` but still doesn't get saved there.

Comment: `coords.shp` needs to be passed as string - `'coords.shp'`

Comment: [@martinfleis], i just passed it to a string and got the error: "CPLE_AppDefinedError: Failed to create file r'C:\\Users\\...'\coords_gdf.shp: No error"

Comment: @user2856, the shapefile isn't saved to the filepath given. Outfilepath is the variable which stores the path where the shapefile should be saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have a `return` statement before you write out your file, so the
   `coords_gdf.to_file(etc...)` will never get run as the `geodf`
   function has already returned.
2. Then you'll get `NameError: name 'coords.shp' is not defined` because python will interpret `coords.shp` as a `variable.attribute` instead of a string.  Wrap it in quotes and use `os.path.join`
3. You try to do too much in your `geodf` function, just have it create and return a `GeoDataframe` and then do whatever you want with it later.

For example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
import os


def geodf(coords, epsg_code):

    coords_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
    coords_poly = Polygon(coords)
    coords_poly

    coords_gdf.loc[0, 'geometry'] = coords_poly
    coords_gdf.crs = from_epsg(epsg_code)
    coords_gdf.crs

    return coords_gdf

outdir = '/tmp'
outfilepath = os.path.join(outdir, 'coords_gdf.shp')
a_coords = [(659337, 737770), (659335, 737703), (659329, 737702) ,(659328, 737700), (659282, 737700), (659268, 737749), (659296, 737767)] #example
epsg_code = 32630

coords_gdf = geodf(a_coords, epsg_code)
coords_gdf.plot(color='brown')
coords_gdf.to_file(outfilepath)
```

Comment: This was helpful, thank you.